# Create an array or object of elements with the same dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently the following jQuery collection / object:

`[li.row-0, li.row-1, li.row-2, li-row-2, li.row-2, li.row-3]`

Each class name is dynamically added to each element by a previous method. The only consistent part of the class name is `row-`. The number can be anywhere from 0 - ∞.

I want to create a new array or object of elements that are grouped by same dynamic class name:

```
[li.row-0]
[li.row-1]
[li.row-2, li.row-2, li.row-2, li.row-2]
[li.row-3]
```

The above is just a guess of the outcome, as I am not 100% sure how best to achieve this.

The aim is to be able to loop through `.row-0, .row-1, .row-2, .row-3` and do something with the elements in each individual row.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, if anything. You'll be looked on much more favourably if you show you've made the effort to try and solve your problem yourself before asking here `:)`

Comment: @Bojangles I wish I had code to share, but I sadly failed to get my head around the logic. Asking a question was my last resort. :(

Comment: That's why I included "if anything", and it's good this was your last resort instead of your first like so many lazy programmers out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this :

```
var map = [].reduce.call(arr, function(map, v){
     (map[v.className]||(map[v.className]=[])).push(v);
     return map;
}, {});
var arr2 = [];
for (var className in map)  arr2.push(map[className]);
```

The `reduce` builds a map having as keys the class names and with values the arrays of the elements having that class name.

I use `[].reduce.call(arr,` instead of `arr.reduce(` so that it works for standard arrays, jQuery collections, nodelists, etc.

Then the loop builds an array from that map. You might find the map more useful than the final array.

Comment: Perfect! The map, as you mentioned, is super useful.

Answer (score 1):

This shows you a general way of achieving this, though you're probably using elements rather than strings, but hopefully this will help

```
var tst = ['li.row-0','li.row-1','li.row-2','li.row-2','li.row-2','li.row-3'];
var grouped = [];
for(var i in tst)
{
    var text = tst[i];
    var num = text.replace('li.row-','');
    if(!grouped[num]) grouped[num] = [];
    grouped[num].push(text);
}
console.log(grouped);//[["li.row-0"], ["li.row-1"], ["li.row-2", "li.row-2", "li.row-2"], ["li.row-3"]]
```

Using elements:

```
var tst = [li.row-0,li.row-1,li.row-2,li.row-2,li.row-2,li.row-3];
var grouped = [];
for(var i in tst)
{
    var text = tst[i].className;
    var num = text.replace('row-','');
    if(!grouped[num]) grouped[num] = [];
    grouped[num].push(text);
}
console.log(grouped);//[["li.row-0"], ["li.row-1"], ["li.row-2", "li.row-2", "li.row-2"], ["li.row-3"]]
```

This method is more verbose and allows more complex grouping if need be (if other attributes come into play)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following:

```
var arr = ['li.row-0', 'li.row-1', 'li.row-2', 'li.row-2', 'li.row-2', 'li.row-3'];
var result = {};
$.each(arr, function (index, item) {
    var ind = item.toString().split('row-')[1];
    (result[ind] || (result[ind] = [])).push(item);
});
console.log(result);
```